# Calculate double integral with specific region

Tags: integration

I need to calculate

$$\iint\frac{dx\,dy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$$
$$x^2 + y^2 < 2y$$

I tried to solve this via polar coordinates

$$0 \leq r < 2\sin(\phi)$$
$$0 \leq \phi \leq 2\pi$$

So, our integral becomes

$$\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \int_0^{2\sin(\phi)} \, dr $$

which seems to be wrong because of $$r < 2\sin(\phi)$$

Comment: $$x^2+y^2<2y$$ is equivalent to $$x^2+(y-1)^2<1$$

Comment: You probably only need to integrate from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2,$ since there is no portion of your region in the left two quadrants.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews that would be true for $r = 2 \cos\theta$. Here there is no portion of the region in bottom two quadrants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \iint\frac{dx\,dy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$$

Region is $x^2+y^2 \leq 2y$.

So if you are using $x = r \cos \theta, y = r \sin\theta$,

$$r \leq 2 \sin\theta, 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi.$$

This is a circle centered at $(0, 1)$ with radius $1$. As you are measuring radius from the origin, $r = 2 \sin\theta$ on the circle and note that the complete circle forms for $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$.

So integral becomes $ \ \displaystyle \int_0^\pi \int_0^{2 \sin\theta}\,dr \ d\theta $